# How to create reusable fetch for different json structures in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I use fetch in different components:

```
    fetch(url)
      .then(result => {
        if (!result.ok) {
          throw new Error("HTTP error " + result.status)
        }
        return result.json()
      })
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          data: result,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {})
```

But json data has a different structure:

```
  state = {
    data: [],
  }
```

and

```
  state = {
    data: {
      items: [],
    }
  }
```

I want to make one reusable function component to both structures. How to create it, if it is possible?
I tried to use this

```
export function getList(url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(result => {
            if (!result.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + result.status)
            }
            return result.json()
        })
        .then(result => {
            return result
        })
        .catch(error => {})
}
```

With the same call for both

```
      this.setState({
        data: getList(url),
      })
```

But got an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Await/async would greatly shorten the code sample. (then the function you are trying to create might not be even needed.)

Comment: That is exactly the problem, you are not using the data nor the promise returned from the fetch. So you're setting the `data` property to `undefined` with the above code.

Comment: @Kudlas Is this the best practice? Should I avoid reusable fetch?

Comment: @Christiaan Should I pass state data to the function explicitly?

Comment: @MDspb Not necessarily (avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error 'But got an error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' cause the fuction is returning undefined. You need to **return** fetch

```
export function getList(url) {
    return fetch(url)
....
}
```

Now, assuming getList returns data in this format

```
data: {
      items: [],
    }
```

You keep the returned data same, and just change mappings for components.
So basically you reuse fetch call.

1st component :

```
async getSetData(url){
    const data = await getList(url);
        this.setState({
                data: data,
              })
}
```

2nd component :

```
async getSetData(url){
    const data = await getList(url);
        this.setState({
                data: data.items,
              });
}
```